# Using Sharp to compress image size without changing aspect ratio of the image

Tags: node.js, sharp

I have an aws image file and Iam compressing the image using sharp , but after compressing, the file size is increasing hugely . In my case I have an image size of 6.5MB , which after compressing it is becoming 19.5MB.

The following is my code :

```
const width = parseInt(image.height);
const height = parseInt(image.width);

var getObjectParams = {
  Bucket: BUCKET,
  Key: FILE_NAME
}

  s3.getObject(getObjectParams).promise()
    .then(data => {
      sharp(data.Body)
       .resize(width, height)
        .ignoreAspectRatio()
        .toFormat('png')
        .toBuffer()
        .then((buffer) => {
         ........
         ........
    }
```

I have even tried using `.max()` ,

```
 sharp(data.Body)
 .withoutEnlargement()
 .resize(width, height)
 .toFormat('png')
 .toBuffer()
```

The same issue , file size is increasing . In my case the image aspect ratio should be maintained. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you ask about this on https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues already? If not, please do that, because as an open source library, that is literally the first place to ask.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes i have asked in github https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1307

Comment: Good. Looks like you'll want to edit your question there though, github has a different code formatting format (SO uses indentation, GH uses ``` before and ``` after your code blocks)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , Thanks for your suggestion ,I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with `Sharp` but yet this is a nice & amazing package. Read the `Sharp` [documentation](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#png) for `png`.

If you need to play around with;
`options.quality`, `options.colours`, `options.dither` to compress a significant amount of any PNG image and according to its doc,

> **requires libvips compiled with support for libimagequant**

So you need the help of `libimagequant` to achieve your goal.
According to the site, **libimagequant** is a Small, portable C library for high-quality conversion of RGBA images to 8-bit indexed-color (palette) images.

Instead you can use [this NPM PACKAGE called imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin) and I am sure it uses the same method to compress PNG images. With a small piece of code as below, you can reduce the size of PNG.

```
const files = await imagemin(['images/*.{png}'], {
    destination: 'build/images',
        plugins: [
            imageminJpegtran(),
            imageminPngquant({
                quality: [0.6, 0.8]
            })
        ]
});
```

Play around with `quality: [0.6, 0.8]` like `quality: [0.2, 0.2]` to reduce the size and you can pass a single image file like `const files = await imagemin(['fileName.png']`